# Can I do a search in multiple fields using vue-select.

Tags: javascript, search, vue.js, vue-select

It's searching in the "label" field as default. But I want to do search in both of them (value, label). Any advice?

```js
Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect);

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://unpkg.com/vue@2.1.10"></script>
<script src="http://unpkg.com/vue-select@2.0.0"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app" class="container-fluid">
    <h2>VueSelect Basic Example</h2>
    <v-select :options="[{'value': 'ABC', 'label': 'Lorem ipsum dolor 1'}, {'value': 'CDE', 'label': 'Lorem ipsum dolor 2'}, {'value': 'VYZ', 'label': 'Lorem ipsum dolor 3'}, ]"></v-select>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can choose one field but not both of them

Comment: so, is there any other solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In last version 2.5.1 of `vue-select` I see props like `filterBy` and `filter`.
I think you can use just `filterBy` to achieve what you want.
From source code comments:

> Callback to determine if the provided option should
>          match the current search text. Used to determine
>          if the option should be displayed.

Here is example(search by `name` and `lastname` even without label):

```js
Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    options: [{ label: "1", name: "John", lastname: "Johnson" }, { label: "2", name: "Justin", lastname: "Well" }],
    myFilter: (option, label, search) => {
      let temp = search.toLowerCase();
      return option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(temp) > -1 || 
      option.lastname.toLowerCase().indexOf(temp) > -1
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="http://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.2"></script>
<script src="http://unpkg.com/vue-select@2.5.1"></script>
<div id="app">
    <h2>VueSelect Basic Example</h2>
    <v-select :options="options" :filter-by="myFilter"></v-select>
  </div>
```

Links to source code props lines:

[filterBy](https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select/blob/master/src/components/Select.vue#L634)

[filter](https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select/blob/master/src/components/Select.vue#L652)

Comment: Thank you, that is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

you can achive this by another way. *v-autocomplete* is another built-in component by which you can search through your select items.

```
<v-autocomplete
  :rules="formRules"
  v-model="form"
  :items="selectItems"
  menu-props="auto"
  label="autocomplete"
>
  <template slot="selection" slot-scope="data">
    {{ 'name: ' + data.item.name +' last name: ' + data.item.lastname + ' label: ' + data.item.label }}
  </template>
  <template slot="item" slot-scope="data">
    {{ 'name: ' + data.item.name +' last name: ' + data.item.lastname + ' label: ' + data.item.label }}
  </template>
</v-autocomplete>
```

now by searching in the *v-autocomplete* searchbar the list items are filtered based on the searched text.